# server side pagination for pivot table in ag grid

Tags: javascript, pivot, ag-grid, server-side-rendering

i have aggrid table with pivot mode true.since my grid data is very large i would like to add pagination.but pagination is added successfully with my below code

```
const columnDefs = [
{
 field: 'athlete',
 minWidth: 200,
 enableRowGroup: true,
 enablePivot: true,
},
{
 field: 'age',
 enableValue: true,
},
{
 field: 'country',
 minWidth: 200,
 enableRowGroup: true,
 enablePivot: true,
 headerValueGetter: countryHeaderValueGetter,
},
{
 field: 'year',
 enableRowGroup: true,
 enablePivot: true,
},
{
 field: 'date',
 minWidth: 180,
 enableRowGroup: true,
 enablePivot: true,
},
{
 field: 'sport',
 minWidth: 200,
 enableRowGroup: true,
 enablePivot: true,
},
{
 field: 'gold',
 hide: true,
 enableValue: true,
 toolPanelClass: 'tp-gold',
},
{
 field: 'silver',
 hide: true,
 enableValue: true,
 toolPanelClass: ['tp-silver'],
},
{
 field: 'bronze',
 hide: true,
 enableValue: true,
 toolPanelClass: function (params) {
   return 'tp-bronze';
 },
},
{
 headerName: 'Total',
 field: 'totalAgg',
 valueGetter:
   'node.group ? data.totalAgg : data.gold + data.silver + data.bronze',
},
];

const gridOptions = {
columnDefs: columnDefs,
defaultColDef: {
 flex: 1,
 minWidth: 100,
 sortable: true,
 filter: true,
},  pagination: true, 
             rowModelType: 'infinite',
            
             cacheBlockSize: 100, // you can have your custom page size
             paginationPageSize: 100,
sideBar: {
             toolPanels: [
               {
                 id: 'columns',
                 labelDefault: 'Columns',
                 labelKey: 'columns',
                 iconKey: 'columns',
                 toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
               },
             ],
             defaultToolPanel: 'columns',
           },
rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
};


function countryHeaderValueGetter(params) {
switch (params.location) {
 case 'csv':
   return 'CSV Country';
 case 'clipboard':
   return 'CLIP Country';
 case 'columnToolPanel':
   return 'TP Country';
 case 'columnDrop':
   return 'CD Country';
 case 'header':
   return 'H Country';
 default:
   return 'Should never happen!';
}
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
const dataSource = {
             rowCount: undefined, // behave as infinite scroll
             getRows: function (params) {
                var lastRow=-1;
                  fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((data) => {var data1=data.splice(params.start,100);params.successCallback(data1, lastRow) ;console.log(data,'data')});
                                       
                
             },
           };            
         gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
         

});
```

but I do not know what is wrong or is it possible to have server side pagination in aggrid or not .while trying I am getting row data but data is not aggregated when i choose min or max or count data is not changing in values section. Can anyone say where i am wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not apply min, max or count on the entire set of data and than to return the subset requested by the paginator. Here you load just a static json and extract the data for the "(params.start,100);".

Answer (score 0):

Here the data being sent to AG Grid itself contains 100 records. Hence it can only perform aggregation for that if we have to provide the whole data set to AG Grid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).